# I can see the directory on my finder window but cant connect to it with ruby Dir.chdir(".")

Tags: ruby

I can see the directory in my finder window but I am unable to connect to a network folder with ruby, is there another way I should approach this?

this returns false

```
puts Dir.exists?("../../../../Public")
```

I know it exists because I can see it

[image]

Comment: _Sidenote_: MacOS shows the “human-readable” representation of the file system, not the file system as it is in reality.

Comment: Other Sidenote: When I'm not sure, which is the "correct" path of my directory, I open the Terminal.app, and drag the directory from the Finder window into the Terminal, where it appears as the correct absolute path to the directory. I can then use copy&paste to copy the path into the text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually mapped network drives like "Public" in your picture above are mounted on the file system mounted under `/Volumes/`. Open Terminal and use the `mount` command to check where it's actually mounted to. It's unlikely you'll be able to get to it like you've specified.

(The view you have there is a Finder view that doesn't actually correspond to a specific point of your system's tree. "Macintosh HD" is most likely `/` and network drives, secondary drives, and images usually get mounted under `/Volumes`, the "Network" and "Remote Disk" entries I don't think correspond to anywhere in particular on the tree, but I'd need to look that up to know for certain.)

Comment: thank you much! Volumes was correct, within volumes was my Public directory

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand the path.

```
puts Dir.exist?(File.expand_path("../../../../Public"))
```